# How to fill in different color for the area in ellipse between 2 line in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

So I have layer with ellipse inside,I divide it to 8 parts using line tools.Now I want to fill in the area between 2 line in different color,but how to do that??

Now my image look like this.The whole area until top of the artboard I want to fill in different color.Am I do like this correct?Or have a better solution?

Sorry if this is a silly question,I totally newbie and totally no idea how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget that. Here's a better way, and it's all vector, so it will be fully rescalable.

1. Drop a horizontal and vertical guide in the middle of the image, where you want the middle of the circle to be.
2. With Smart Guides enabled, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click with the Ellipse Tool over the intersection of the guides, while still holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, also hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and drag the circle. This will constrain the ellipse to a circle, with the centre at the guide intersection.
3. Drop guides at the top, bottom, right and left of the circle - they should snap if you have already enabled Smart Guides.
4. With the Pen Tool set to "Shape", begin at the middle of the circle where the guides meet, and click points to make a triangular section which goes outside the ellipse. Finish by closing the path by clicking in the centre point again. Choose any fill colour you want.
5. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click in between the two layers in the layers panel. This will turn the layer into a clipping path.

Repeat steps 4 and 5 for additional segments.

[image: Illustrated example showing layers and clipping paths]